# Using External JWT token ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to asp.net Core and still in learning phase, I have a Rest API which is handling all identity and returns a JWT against authorized request.
I have now created a new .NET Core web application and i have consumed that API to get Token, basic flow for this new application is

`.NET CORE Web Applicaiton -> Calls(With UserCredentials) WebAPI to get Token -> Web Api returns a token with all claims including roles`

I have accomplished all of above but i want to know the best practice for state management of above application,

I have two controllers named Cars and Boats
Can i use sessions to hold token and check on every request to each of controllers and check if token is not expired and it contains the role for the requested controller or is there any other better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session to save token, but session is saved on the server, so I do not suggest you use session to save token.

Better method: save the token into a cookie or other web storage, when you request an action which has been protected by `[Authorize]`, the request needs to carry the token, other requests don't need to carry token.

About checking if token is expired, there are following methods.

1. you can set the expire time for a long time, when it is expired, the user will log in again.
2. when the client get a token, you can add a listen event to listen the expire time. Before it is expired, trigger a function to request a new token.

Comment: @Baba Fooka, could you accept this answer? Your approval is my greatest reward.